# What would i use to switch to a frame in Playwright

Tags: playwright

In selenium there is a method `switchTo` that can be used to switch to a frame.
Is there anything similar in Playwright?

Comment: Are you looking for https://playwright.dev/docs/frames?

Comment: Not really. I'm rather looking to switch the Page to a Frame and then back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Context of Selenium `driver` vs Playwright `page`

Tl:dr - Driving the browser and everything inside it vs interacting with the browser and specific tabs (or “pages”) within it

Not exactly. Playwright takes a slightly different approach. Instead of just a `driver` which contains all the methods to drive the browser and anything within it, Playwright splits this into more specific pieces - `browser`, `context`, and `page`.

[Browser](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browser) is for the browser itself as a whole, which can contain many contexts and tabs.

[BrowserContext](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsercontext) for specific independent browsing sessions (for instance, a tab opened by another tab will be part of the same session or context).

[Page](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page) for controlling a specific tab (or “page”) within the browser/context. Each separate tab will have its own Page instance to represent it.

The benefits of this include being able to share context between pages, working with multiple tabs simultaneously more easily, and other areas where the separation is useful. You’re not tied down to just using one driver instance for everything.

### Specific Answer

For your question there’s an added piece, [Frames](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-frame), which you can access directly from a Page still, while also allowing you to interact with it separately/as its own entity or “page” in a way. The main page is really just its own top frame with page content, and each iframe is basically its own page with its own content.

The closest thing to switchTo here would be to just use `.frame()` to get the specific Frame and interact with it, whether by calling .frame each time or just storing, using, and passing around the frame itself. It has most of the main methods of Page you would use/need anyway, so in many cases can just be used in its place. So while not exactly like switchTo in making the page interact with the other frame (or tab) and having to switch back, because that was actually telling the driver to drive one vs the other, you can just access the Frame itself to interact with for those parts, and keep the page representing the full page.

Note that there is a difference between FrameLocator and Frame. The first solely provides a way to locate elements within an iframe, whereas the second is like another Page specific to that frame allowing you to interact with it similarly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The syntax is a bit different than Selenium but the idea is more or less the same. You can use [frameLocator](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-framelocator) to drill down to the frame and interact with elements contained within. Think of it like `switchTo()`.

For example, you have a `<iframe>` with a login form inside, and want to fill it:

```js
const email = 'foo@bar.com'
await page.frameLocator('#sillyWidget iframe').locator('#username').click();
for (let i = 0; i < email.length; i += 1) {
  await page.keyboard.press(email[i], { delay: 20 + Math.random() * 5 });
}
```

List all the frames on the page:

```js
const frames = await page.childFrames();
for (const frame of frames) {
  console.debug('Frame --> ' + frame.url())
}
```

Listen for new frames:

```js
page.on('frameattached', frames => frames.forEach(frame => console.debug('Frame attached' + frame.url())));
```

Edit:

A `Page` already comprises the main `Frame` and all subframes, so the `switchTo()` analogy kind of breaks down in that regard. The frame already exists
inside the `Page`, so switching to it doesn't make sense.

In the case you want to perform many operations in a child frame, just grab a reference to it, and work with it like you would a `Page` (nearly all the same functions are available).

Also note that:

- Playwright uses [ChromeDevTools](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/) protocol to speak to the browser.
- Selenium uses [JSONW](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/legacy/json_wire_protocol/).

They are fundamentally different beasts, though some syntax is the same. CDP is orders of magnitude more powerful, and directly supported by chromium-based browsers by design.

```js
const frame = page.frame('frame-login'); // reference to your frame
await frame.fill('#username-input', 'Phillip Masse'); // fill an input inside the frame
// [1]
await Promise.all([page.click('#btn'), page.waitForNavigation()]; // now do stuff on the page level
```

[1]: If memory serves, in selenium to accomplish this we'd need to `driver.switch_to_default_content()` here.

Comment: So I cannot switch the page to a new frame but rather must explicitly interact with the frame itself using the Frame class. This seems to be less generic than the selenium API and makes it a bit harder to use generalised page objects. It is not possible to actually switch my Page to the frame and then back?

Comment: @doberkofler Check the updated answer. IIRC in selenium, if you `switch_to()`, you can't then start working with stuff on the root frame. That limitation is a consequence of how [JSONW](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/legacy/json_wire_protocol/) works with the webdriver. It seems like a limitation, not a benefit, no?

Answer (score 1):

I want to clarify provided answers in a simple way. In case of `iframe` under the DOM:

```py
...
page.goto(URL)

# work with iframe
frame = page.frame_locator(iframe_selector_here)  # e.g: "[title=canvas]"
frame.get_by_text("Submit").click()

# switch back to main frame
page.locator("[data-test=whatever]").click()
...
```